# "R" is wrong, why?

Tags: android

I started coding since some months with some help and I want to code a own app. I Tried to test it on my phone, but there are some bugs. Why is every "R.id.Number3" codes wrong, but only the "R". I can't fix it. And there is the problem, when I write
 import android.R;
then is the end wrong. why?
sry for the bad english

```
package com.projektarbeit.felix043.projektarbeit;

import android.content.DialogInterface;   
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


Button plus1Button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.plus1_btn);
Button minus1Button = (Button)  findViewById(R.id.minus1_btn);

plus1Button.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Number1);
        String str = editText.getText().toString();
        int Zahl = Integer.parseInt(str);

        Zahl = Zahl + 1;

        editText.setText(Integer.toString(Zahl));
    }
});

minus1Button.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Number1);
        String str = editText.getText().toString();
        int Zahl = Integer.parseInt(str);

        Zahl = Zahl - 1;

        editText.setText(Integer.toString(Zahl));
     }
});



    Button plus2Button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.plus2_btn);
    Button minus2button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.minus2_btn);

    plus2Button.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Number2);
            String str = editText.getText().toString();
            int Zahl = Integer.parseInt(str);

            Zahl = Zahl + 1;

            editText.setText(Integer.toString(Zahl));
        }
});

    minus2button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View v) {
          EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Number2);
          String str = editText.getText().toString();
          int Zahl = Integer.parseInt(str);

          Zahl = Zahl - 1;

          editText.setText(Integer.toString(Zahl));
      }

        });

    Button plus3Button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.plus3_btn);
    Button minus3button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.minus3_btn);

    plus3Button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Number3);
            String str = editText.getText().toString();
            int Zahl = Integer.parseInt(str);

            Zahl = Zahl + 1;

            editText.setText(Integer.toString(Zahl));
        }

    });

    minus3button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Number3);
            String str = editText.getText().toString();
            int Zahl = Integer.parseInt(str);

            Zahl = Zahl - 1;

            editText.setText(Integer.toString(Zahl));
        }

    });

    Button plus4button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.plus4_btn);
    Button minus4button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.minus4_btn);

    plus4button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Number4);
            String str = editText.getText().toString();
            int Zahl = Integer.parseInt(str);

            Zahl = Zahl + 1;

            editText.setText(Integer.toString(Zahl));
        }

    });

    minus4button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Number4);
            String str = editText.getText().toString();
            int Zahl = Integer.parseInt(str);

            Zahl = Zahl - 1;

            editText.setText(Integer.toString(Zahl));
        }

    });

    Button plus5button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.plus5_btn);
    Button minus5button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.minus5_btn);

    plus4button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Number5);
            String str = editText.getText().toString();
            int Zahl = Integer.parseInt(str);

            Zahl = Zahl + 1;

            editText.setText(Integer.toString(Zahl));
        }

    });

    minus5button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Number5);
            String str = editText.getText().toString();
            int Zahl = Integer.parseInt(str);

            Zahl = Zahl - 1;

            editText.setText(Integer.toString(Zahl));
        }

    });




    }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Comment: You are not importing your R.java class.  http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidDevelopmentProblems/article.html

Comment: just change ActionBarActivity to Activity  and right click on project ->refresh      go to project on toolbar select clean and select project run the application

Comment: ctrl +shift+O and choose the right classes to import will solve your problem. (specially yourPackageName.R)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the `package name` at the top of your project right?

However, rebuild your project (Go to "build" and then click on "rebuild project").

Answer (score -1):

Try to clean your project. In intellij you can find it in Build -> Clean project.

Answer (score -2):

You should import this

```
import com.projektarbeit.felix043.projektarbeit.R;
```

If that still shows R as an error, then you have a problem in your XML documents that is causing them to not be parsed correctly.

If you are using Eclipse, you can edit "Window-->Preferences-->Android-->Build-->Build Output" and set it to Verbose.

Then rebuild. This will give you more information about any build errors in the Console and allow you to see which, if any, XML has an error.

Comment: Voting down genuine comments, without adding a comment, is against the grain of this website. Whoever you two are, own up and explain _why_ you voted down many of the sensible answers to this question.

Answer (score -2):

Just Clean and Build your project

If the error is still there, then remove ActionBarActivity and use  *extends Activity*  indstead